# change only display of \thesubsection not the actual value

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\label{sec:subsection}
\appendix
\chapter{An appendix}
We refer to  \vref{sec:subsection}.
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

The problem is that I would like to have Section 1.1.A here but I need to change the subsection counter to display the subsection heading the way I want. What's the workaround here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a trailing period only after subsection numbers, the best way is to redefine `\@seccntformat` (see section 6.6 in the `memoir` manual, p. 107).

Then we can use the `\p@<counter>` feature of the LaTeX kernel. When a `\label` command is given, LaTeX uses the last “refstepped” counter, prefixed by `\p@<counter>`. Usually `\p@subsection` is empty, but we can redefine it.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% We add an optional suffix to numbers when printing the section header
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname\csname suffix@#1\endcsname\quad}

\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

% Access to the internals
\makeatletter
% redefine the prefix to the subsection number when \ref is used
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\thesection.}
% only \suffix@subsection needs a definition
\newcommand{\suffix@subsection}{.}
\makeatother

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\label{sec:subsection}
\appendix
\chapter{An appendix}
We refer to  \vref{sec:subsection}.
\end{document}
```

Since we don't define `\suffix@section`, LaTeX will change it automatically to `\relax` when finding `\csname suffix@section\endcsname`.

[image]

[image]

If you also want to change format for the number in the header, then add also a prefix:

```
\setsecnumformat{%
  \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \csname suffix@#1\endcsname\quad}
```

and then define accordingly `\prefix@subsection` and `\suffix@subsection`:

```
\makeatletter
% redefine the prefix to the subsection number when \ref is used
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\thesection.}
% only \prefix@subsection and \suffix@subsection need a definition
\newcommand{\prefix@subsection}{\begingroup\large}
\newcommand{\suffix@subsection}{.\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

The group will apply `\large` only to the section number.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly fine. before \`Alph{subsection}` I am also changing the font size using `fontspec` scaling feature. The size change gets reflected while referring to subsection letter (large 'A'). Where can you set the font to `normalsize` for it?

Comment: @rowman Don't add formatting instructions to `\thesubsection`. It's better to add a prefix just like I added a suffix. A new version is in the works.